# Issue in validation of password due to runat server in asp .net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, validation

I made validation to the form , every field is using runat server. Every field is validating perfectly fine, but in password field i get an error of "paswords do not match". when i remove runat server from the same field it works fine. please help me to sort out this issue.

my code is as:

```
<asp:TextBox  runat="server"  class="validate[required] text-input" type="password" name="password" id="password"></asp:TextBox>  
 <asp:TextBox  runat="server"  class="validate[required,equals[password]] text-input"  type="password" name="password2" id="password2">  </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the default validation tools that come with ASP.net templates?

Comment: Add  `ClientIdMode="Static"` attribute to textboxes.